# Filter first element that match predicate with multiple checks

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to filter a list of POJOs with two different predicates using a stream.

```
public class Toy {
  public boolean isRed();
  public boolean isBlue();
  public boolean isGreen();
}

public class RedBlueExtravaganza {
  public RedBlueExtravaganza(RedToy rt, BlueToy bt) {
    //construct
  }
}

// Wrappers around Toy with more verbose names
public class RedToy extends Toy { }
public class BlueToy extends Toy { }
public class GreenToy extends Toy { }
```

Basically, I want the first red and the first blue toy in the list of Toy objects.

```
List<Toy> toyList = Arrays.asList(greenToy1, redToy1, greenToy2, redToy2, blueToy1);
```

I want to write a stream that does the following:

```
RedBlueExtravaganza firstRedBlueList = toyList.stream()
       // get first red but keep rest of list
       // get first blue but keep rest of list
       // discard rest of list
       // map to a Tuple (or something) to distinguish the one red and one blue toy
       // map to RedBlueExtravaganza
       .findFirst()
       .get();

log.info(firstRedBlueList); // now contains redToy1, blueToy1
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution which traverses your list only once, giving you the first red and blue toys at the end. We can filter out all the other irrelevent colors and then create a map whose key is whether the toy is red and the value is the first toy matching the given criteria. Here's how it looks.

```
Map<Boolean, Toy> firstRedAndBlueToysMap = toyList.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.isBlue() || t.isRed())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Toy::isRed, t -> t, (a, b) -> a));
Toy firstRedToy = firstRedAndBlueToysMap.get(true);
Toy firstBlueToy = firstRedAndBlueToysMap.get(false);
```

And here's a one step approach to solve your problem.

```
RedBlueExtravaganza firstRedAndBlueToyPair = toyList.stream()
    .filter(t -> t.isBlue() || t.isRed())
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toMap(Toy::isRed, 
           t -> t, (a, b) -> a),
        m -> new RedBlueExtravaganza(m.get(true), m.get(false))));
```

P.S. For this to work you need to have the following constructor in your `RedBlueExtravaganza` class contrary to the one you have provided above.

```
public RedBlueExtravaganza(Toy rt, Toy bt) {
    if (!(rt instanceof RedToy) || !(bt instanceof BlueToy))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    // remainder omitted.
}
```

Comment: You would still need to cast the `Toy` object to map to the `RedBlueExtravaganza` using its constructor which accepts `RedToy` and `BlueToy` objects such as  `m -> new RedBlueExtravaganza((RedToy) m.get(true), (BlueToy) m.get(false))`

Comment: I would rather use this constructor `public RedBlueExtravaganza(Toy rt, Toy bt)` and do the validation inside it.

Comment: With an explicitly named class `RedBlueExtravaganza`, wouldn't consider it a very great design though. But still, if that's what you meant, it would be worth mentioning in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I like [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58618100/11733759), similar solution can be with reduce and List as "Tuple (or something)"

```java
List<Toy> reduceToList = toyList.stream()
      .filter(t -> t.isBlue() || t.isRed())
      .map(t -> Arrays.asList(t, t))
      .reduce(Arrays.asList(null, null), (a, c) -> a.get(0) == null && c.get(0).isRed() ?
              Arrays.asList(c.get(0), a.get(1)) : (a.get(1) == null && c.get(1).isBlue() ?
              Arrays.asList(a.get(0), c.get(1)) : a)
      );
```

If both values are not null then you can map to `RedBlueExtravaganza`

Answer (score 0):

One way which first comes into my mind is to use 2 streams for finding first red and blue toy object, respectively. Then merge them into one stream by using `Stream.concat()` so that you can add more oprations for this.

**Code snippet**

```
RedBlueExtravaganza firstRedBlueList = Stream
    .concat(
            toyList.stream().filter(t -> t.isRed())
            .findFirst()
            .map(Collections::singletonList)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
            .stream(),
            toyList.stream().filter(t -> t.isBlue())
            .findFirst()
            .map(Collections::singletonList)
            .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList)
            .stream())
    .map(x -> {
        RedToy rt = new RedToy();
        BlueToy bt = new BlueToy();
        ...
        return new RedBlueExtravaganza(rt, bt);})
    .findFirst()
    .get();
```

Comment: No need for constructs like `.findFirst() .map(Collections::singletonList) .orElseGet(Collections::emptyList) .stream()`. Just use `limit(1)`. But you can’t coerce the elements via `map`. Note how your example code isn’t even using the `x` parameter…